# Ext JS buffered scrolling on custom component

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store, infinite-scroll, buffered

Looking at the example for buffered scrolling:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/buffer-grid.html

Am i to assume that this feature is only available on Grids?

I would like to use it with a memory proxy bound to a custom data view that is not a Grid.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extjs doesn´t provide any mechanism out of the box to allow us implement infinite scrolling in  our custom data view, only grids can have that feature. The reason is all the magic is distributed across Store, PagingScroller and Grid to only allow it in Grids and only in Grids.

The PagingScroller, which watches scroll activity, was designed only for grids (or Ext.view.Table), in fact its namespace is pretty clear about it: Ext.grid.PagingScroller.

You could implement a custom solution but the effort would be really big. Then, the shortest answers is No, it is not possible without writing you own costly and risky implementation.